# IF function to determine if SYSDATE-1 or SYSDATE-3 should be used by determining Monday

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I run this report Mon-Fri for the previous day's data and I am trying to figure out how to hard code TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-3) if today is 
Monday (day the report is run) or use TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) for any other workday (mon - fri). I am assuming that this will require an IF, THEN, ELSE statement but am unsure of how to include that properly into my query.

```
SELECT
RRA.LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE AS "LAST MODIFICATION DATE",

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1),'DD-MON-RR') AS "DATA_DATE"

FROM PHOENIX.R_REFERRAL_ACTIVITY RRA
Where 1=1

AND RRA.LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE 
BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1),'DD-MON-RR') AND TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MON-RR')
```

Comment: It's been quite a while since you posted the question, but no answers yet. I saw it back then when you posted it, but didn't understand what you were saying (hoping that it is me, and that someone else will understand it). However, it appears that I was wrong. Could you explain what the first sentence you wrote means? What do "sysdate" and "Monday" mean here? What "subtraction"? If possible, post an example. Also, query you wrote contains a lot of irrelevant columns and joins - try to make it simpler so that we'd understand it easier.

Comment: Good morning Littlefoot,
Thank you for your input. I hope the changes I made to my question and sample of the query makes it easier to understand my question. Still new to posting and the proper wording/ examples for my questions. :)

Comment: Thank you, @Blink; I think I understand now, so I posted an example. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha; OK then, it seems that you'd need to use CASE along with TO_CHAR function which will tell you which day is "today". Have a look, see if it helps.

TEST is just a simple *calendar*, several days in this February. I'm removing Saturdays and Sundays (as you said you're interested in mon - fri only).

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1 c_date,
  3            to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1, 'dy') c_day
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level < 20
  6    )
  7  select
  8    c_date todays_date,
  9    c_day,
 10    --
 11    c_date - case when c_day = 'mon' then 3
 12                  else 1
 13             end previous_work_date,
 14    --
 15    to_char(c_date - case when c_day = 'mon' then 3
 16                          else 1
 17                     end, 'dy') previous_work_day
 18  from test
 19  where c_day not in ('sat', 'sun')
 20  order by 1;

TODAYS_DAT C_D PREVIOUS_W PRE
---------- --- ---------- ---
01.02.2018 thu 31.01.2018 wed
02.02.2018 fri 01.02.2018 thu
05.02.2018 mon 02.02.2018 fri
06.02.2018 tue 05.02.2018 mon
07.02.2018 wed 06.02.2018 tue
08.02.2018 thu 07.02.2018 wed
09.02.2018 fri 08.02.2018 thu
12.02.2018 mon 09.02.2018 fri
13.02.2018 tue 12.02.2018 mon
14.02.2018 wed 13.02.2018 tue
15.02.2018 thu 14.02.2018 wed
16.02.2018 fri 15.02.2018 thu
19.02.2018 mon 16.02.2018 fri

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```